# Constraint violation for the primary key being generated by Hibernate and manually through script

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have a scenario in which I am performing some Database(PostgreSQL) operations.

Some predefined entries are inserted in tables using the shell script in which I am giving **assoc_id** which is a NOT NULL constraint and primary key as well. For the same operation, the user can input values using UI for which assoc_id are auto-generated using **hibernate sequence**.

Now the plot is let's say pre-defined entries through shell script are given below as:

```
INSERT INTO config.profile_backend_point_asso(assoc_id,enabled,end_point_id,profile_id) VALUES
(1,true,1,1),
(2,true,2,1),
(3,true,3,1),
(4,true,4,1),
(5,true,5,1),
(6,true,6,1),
(7,true,7,1),
(8,true,8,1),
(9,true,9,1),
(10,true,10,1);
```

Now through UI user insert some entries and there may be a scenario where hibernate generates **assoc_id** as 11 just after the last insertion through the shell script.

Now let's say some more pre-defined data needs to be inserted through the shell script in such case we might be unaware of the last sequence generation of hibernate for the same table and new entries inserted through the script are as below:-
INSERT INTO config.profile_backend_point_asso(assoc_id,enabled,end_point_id,profile_id) VALUES
(11,true,11,1),
(12,true,12,1),
(13,false,13,1),
(14,true,14,1),
(15,true,15,1);

In such situation, the data through script will not get inserted as **assoc_id** 11 is already present which was inserted using UI.

Now how can I sync both the script and UI entries so that this situation may not occur?

NOTE: UI code is backed by Java code for auto-generation of **assoc_id** as below:

```
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "hibernate_sequence", sequenceName = 
        "hibernate_sequence" , allocationSize=50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
        "hibernate_sequence")
    @Column(name = "assoc_id")
    private long assocId;
```

And if the operation is performed through UI then java code gives the below exception:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different
>   object with the same identifier value was already associated with the
>   session : [com.cavisson.model.ProfileBackendPointAssociation#50];
>   nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A
>   different object with the same identifier value was already associated
>   with the session :
>   [com.cavisson.model.ProfileBackendPointAssociation#50]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:410)

Also, hibernate_sequence is generating ids for all the tables in Database and this is just one such example.

Kindly help me with the workaround or ideas that I can implement to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hard to read. Could You inset formatted code (pseudocode)?

Comment: Why are you not using sequence in those rows entered thru shell script? Hibernate sequence in this case is actually SQL sequence and is maintained by database, not hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

When using a Sequence, as commented, this is a DB issue. You should not provide an ID in insertion since it will be provided on DB. No assoc_id should be used on insert statement.